# Getting some errors on an experimental program, relating to System.out.println

Tags: java

I'm getting a lot of errors in this piece of coding below.

first off, every period between "out" and "println" is drawing a red underline. the error reads, '''- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)'''

Next, line 11's "println" has an error reading "'- Syntax error on token "println", = expected after this token"'

also, the (".......") phrases in lines 7,9, and 12 say, """"Syntax error on token ""(whatever words are in the quotation marks)"", delete this token""".

Finally, line 13's semicolon has an error of """- Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token"""

Thanks for your help in advance! :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tennis_Pro
{
   public static void main(String[]args){
   }

   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Welcome to Tennis Pro. Please enter the name of player one:");
   String playerone=in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("And player two?");
   String playertwo=in.nextLine();
   System.out.println("The players today are "+playerone+" and "+playertwo+". is this correct?");
   System.out.println("type y or n");
   String yorn=in.nextLine();
   if (yorn.equals ("y"))
   {
      //The game will go here
   }
   else if (yorn.equals ("m"))
   {
   } 
}
}
```

Comment: Using your IDE's auto formatting feature can help figure out where your unmatched braces are.  Here, as Roland has already said, it's clear you have accidentally closed your main method block right after declaring it, then again at the end of your actual code.

Comment: Another tip is: don't try to figure out multiple errors at once.  You should never have written this much code before trying to compile it.  Instead you should have compiled it after the very first line of code that you wrote in your main method.  Had you done that, you would have realized your mistake and the other dozen or so lines would not have distracted you from the problem.

Comment: @MarkPeters: You accidentally removed the line numbers, which were referenced by the surrounding text. In many other cases we have marked that as a typical misbehavior by beginners, to refer to lines without marking them. :)

Comment: @Roland: I have, but the correct solution isn't to leave them in but rather mark in the code where the error they're having occurs.  Unfortunately the user here has chosen to reference many different errors which would make that difficult, but they're not pertinent to the question.

Answer (score 2):

All your code should be *inside* the `main` method. But that method starts in line 4 and already ends in line 5. You should move the closing `}` somewhere near line 21.

By the way, the line `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` does not produce an error message from the compiler, since it declares a *field* in the class. The other lines are neither a *variable declaration* nor a *method body* (nor some other element allowed there) and are therefore forbidden directly in a class.